# How to define a method param type in order to accept multiple class names in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, class, generics, methods, parameters

I want to pass as a param of an argument the value below:

```
const myClassesArray = [MyClass1, MyClass2, MyClass3];
```

**I cannot change the classes in the array in order to f.e. make all them extend or implement any other class or interface.**

Therefore the method be like this:

```
myMethod(myClasses){
    // for each myClasses
        new myClasses[i]();
    // for end
}
```

Usage example:

```
myMethod(myClassesArray);
```

Am I able to do it in TS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via constructable function signatures.  Here is how it would look like in your code:

```
class A {
    constructor(input: string) {}
}

class B {
    constructor(input: string) {}
}

class C {
    constructor(input: string) {}
}

function comboParser(parsers: (new (input: string) => any)[]) {
    for (const parser of parsers) {
        const p = new parser("hey");
    }
}

//  these work
comboParser([A, B]);
comboParser([A]);

//  these fail
comboParser([""]);
comboParser([A, ""]);
comboParser([B, C, 5]);
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa7rAPYDsIBcAnAV2Hy0IAoBLHAB2PwC5oDDaBzASkQF9V+KVKEgwAQolQZMuNqXJVaDZqyKceCQYOHgo0AMKS0GbHiLyKNeoxZt1fAalQAzYjjLVcMgLYAjLAAKYIQQAKZUdMFhISyUOKEA7tBWyrZqONzQALwAfNBgOACeXADaALoaUhjOFMmmBNCRIeHQWM6NUeEQlcbS6PX4jdnQ8UlN0ZQARAAWoYWTXADcVehaTigA9BvQgDwbgJH70PizYdAJFADWwlh+gZ1UJbAANNBiFcso2DdBzfewb+tbXYHI6hE7OMDUEBXL53SglSaTf4fa7+b4TB7PBFIz6o2ElMTPfTPACsbyAA)